# Clicking on a picture thumbnail and expanding to the center with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know the best way to ask this, but I will give it a try.

I have thumbnails of 3 photos corresponding to peoples bios.  I am trying to have the thumbnails listed by the bios then give the user the ability to click a thumbnail and have the picture expand to the middle of the screen.  When the user clicks off of the picture, the page returns to normal.

I am sure there is a term for this and I am sure it is an easy jQuery method, but I am having trouble locating the code to do so.

Thanks for any help!

Ryan

Comment: Sounds like you want to just use a lightbox style plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is a lightbox. There any many [jQuery lightbox plugins](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+lightbox). I've had great experience with [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/).

To use them, you could target all anchor tags which have direct children `img` tags, for instance:

```
$('a:has(img)').fancybox();
```

Comment: If the file I am using already needs these scripts to function currently


<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

then if I add the additional ones fancy box lists for me to use the current scripting ceases to work.  How can I remedy this?

Comment: Could you paste your HTML markup to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Will be easier to remedy.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TAgwU/   This is without the fancybox.  What I was saying is when I added the script needed for fancybox at the top of my  page, it rendered the rest of my jscript unusable.  This html part are the 5 images I would like to have a lightbox with.

Comment: You've pasted some of your HTML into the javascript section. Just paste your entire HTML file into the top left box (labeled HTML).

Comment: Your page does not pass validation. Use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (validate by direct input, paste in your HTML) and work on your HTML until it validates.