# Jquery image gallery enlargement

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, jquery-events, image-gallery

Now I have pretty difficult problem..

I found this code on the internet, and was wondering if I can make this effect:
When I click on the big image, or anywhere else where you specify, can my image somehow enlarge or pop out (in the same window) with a dim background.
I've found many scripts with which I can make that happen but somehow I can't implement it into this code.

So here is the code, copy and paste it in your program; every advice will be great:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:0; 
background:#111; 
 
font:11px Verdana,Arial;
}
#slideshow {list-style:none; 
color:#fff}
#slideshow span {display:none}

#wrapper {width:506px; 
margin:50px auto; 
display:none}

#wrapper * {margin:0; 
padding:0}

#fullsize {position:relative;
 width:500px; 
 height:300px;
  
 }
    #image {
width:500px;
}

#image img {position:absolute;
 z-index:25; 
 width:auto}
 
.imgnav {position:absolute; 
width:25%;
 height:306px;
  cursor:pointer;
   z-index:150}
   

#imglink {
    position:absolute;
    height:306px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
   

#thumbnails {margin-top:0px;
position:relative;
top:-55px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;


}

#slidearea {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
float:left; 
position:relative;
 width:500px;
 height:81px; 
 overflow:hidden}
 
#slider {
position:absolute;
 left:0; 
 height:81px;
 width:460px;
 }

#slideleft {
float:left; 
width:20px;
 height:31px;
 margin-top:25px;
 position:relative;
   z-index:100;
 background-color:#222;
 top:50px;
 }
 
 #slideright {
 position:relative;

  z-index:100;
float:right;
 width:20px; 
height:31px; 
top:-60px;
left:-6px;
}

#slideleft:hover {background-color:#333}


#slideright:hover {background-color:#333}


 
#slider img {cursor:pointer; 

}


        
</style>       


</head>
<body>

    <ul id="slideshow">
        
      <li>
        
            <h3></h3>
            <span>photos/sea-turtle.jpg</span>
        <p></p>
        
            <a href="#"><img src="thumbnails/sea-turtle-thumb.jpg" alt="Sea Turtle" /></a> 
            
            </li>
        
    </ul>
    <div id="wrapper">
    
        <div id="fullsize">
        
            <div id="imgprev" class="imgnav" title="Previous Image"></div>
            <div id="imglink"></div>
            <div id="imgnext" class="imgnav" title="Next Image"></div>
            <div id="image"></div>
            <div id="information">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="thumbnails">
            <div id="slideleft" title="Slide Left"></div>
      <div id="slidearea">
                <div id="slider"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="slideright" title="Slide Right"></div>
      </div>
      
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" >


var TINY={};

function $(i){return document.getElementById(i)}
function $$(e,p){p=p||document; return p.getElementsByTagName(e)}

TINY.slideshow=function(n){
    this.infoSpeed=this.imgSpeed=this.speed=10;
    this.thumbOpacity=this.navHover=70;
    this.navOpacity=25;
    this.scrollSpeed=5;
    this.letterbox='#000';
    this.n=n;
    this.c=0;
    this.a=[]
};

TINY.slideshow.prototype={
    init:function(s,z,b,f,q){
        s=$(s);
        var m=$$('li',s), i=0, w=0;
        this.l=m.length;
        this.q=$(q);
        this.f=$(z);
        this.r=$(this.info);
        this.o=parseInt(TINY.style.val(z,'width'));
        if(this.thumbs){
            var u=$(this.left), r=$(this.right);
            u.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.scroll.init("'+this.thumbs+'",-1,'+this.scrollSpeed+')');
            u.onmouseout=r.onmouseout=new Function('TINY.scroll.cl("'+this.thumbs+'")');
            r.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.scroll.init("'+this.thumbs+'",1,'+this.scrollSpeed+')');
            this.p=$(this.thumbs)
        }
        for(i;i<this.l;i++){
            this.a[i]={};
            var h=m[i], a=this.a[i];
            a.t=$$('h3',h)[0].innerHTML;
            a.d=$$('p',h)[0].innerHTML;
            a.l=$$('a',h)[0]?$$('a',h)[0].href:'';
            a.p=$$('span',h)[0].innerHTML;
            if(this.thumbs){
                var g=$$('img',h)[0];
                this.p.appendChild(g);
                w+=parseInt(g.offsetWidth);
                if(i!=this.l-1){
                    g.style.marginRight=this.spacing+'px';
                    w+=this.spacing
                }
                this.p.style.width=w+'px';
                g.style.opacity=this.thumbOpacity/100;
                g.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+this.thumbOpacity+')';
                g.onmouseover=new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,100,5)');
                g.onmouseout=new Function('TINY.alpha.set(this,'+this.thumbOpacity+',5)');
                g.onclick=new Function(this.n+'.pr('+i+',1)')
            }
        }
        
        this.auto?this.is(0,0):this.is(0,1)
    },
    mv:function(d,c){
        var t=this.c+d;
        this.c=t=t<0?this.l-1:t>this.l-1?0:t;
        this.pr(t,c)
    },
    pr:function(t,c){
        clearTimeout(this.lt);
        if(c){
            clearTimeout(this.at)
        }
        this.c=t;
        this.is(t,c)
    },
    is:function(s,c){
        if(this.info){
            TINY.height.set(this.r,1,this.infoSpeed/2,-1)
        }
        var i=new Image();
        i.style.opacity=0;
        i.style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)';
        this.i=i;
        i.onload=new Function(this.n+'.le('+s+','+c+')');
        i.src=this.a[s].p;
        if(this.thumbs){
            var a=$$('img',this.p), l=a.length, x=0;
            for(x;x<l;x++){
                a[x].style.borderColor=x!=s?'':this.active
            }
        }
    },
    le:function(s,c){
        this.f.appendChild(this.i);
        var w=this.o-parseInt(this.i.offsetWidth);
        if(w>0){
            var l=Math.floor(w/2);
            this.i.style.borderLeft=l+'px solid '+this.letterbox;
            this.i.style.borderRight=(w-l)+'px solid '+this.letterbox
        }
        TINY.alpha.set(this.i,100,this.imgSpeed);
        var n=new Function(this.n+'.nf('+s+')');
        this.lt=setTimeout(n,this.imgSpeed*100);
        if(!c){
            this.at=setTimeout(new Function(this.n+'.mv(1,0)'),this.speed*1000)
        }
        if(this.a[s].l!=''){
            this.q.onclick=new Function('window.location="'+this.a[s].l+'"');
            this.q.onmouseover=new Function('this.className="'+this.link+'"');
            this.q.onmouseout=new Function('this.className=""');
            this.q.style.cursor='pointer'
        }else{
            this.q.onclick=this.q.onmouseover=null;
            this.q.style.cursor='default'
        }
        var m=$$('img',this.f);
        if(m.length>2){
            this.f.removeChild(m[0])
        }
    },
    nf:function(s){
        if(this.info){
            s=this.a[s];
            $$('h3',this.r)[0].innerHTML=s.t;
            $$('p',this.r)[0].innerHTML=s.d;
            this.r.style.height='auto';
            var h=parseInt(this.r.offsetHeight);
            this.r.style.height=0;
            TINY.height.set(this.r,h,this.infoSpeed,0)
        }
    }
};

TINY.scroll=function(){
    return{
        init:function(e,d,s){
            e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e); var p=e.style.left||TINY.style.val(e,'left'); e.style.left=p;
            var l=d==1?parseInt(e.offsetWidth)-parseInt(e.parentNode.offsetWidth):0; e.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.scroll.mv(e,l,d,s)},20)
        },
        mv:function(e,l,d,s){
            var c=parseInt(e.style.left); if(c==l){TINY.scroll.cl(e)}else{var i=Math.abs(l+c); i=i<s?i:s; var n=c-i*d; e.style.left=n+'px'}
        },
        cl:function(e){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e); clearInterval(e.si)}
    }
}();

TINY.height=function(){
    return{
        set:function(e,h,s,d){
            e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e); var oh=e.offsetHeight, ho=e.style.height||TINY.style.val(e,'height');
            ho=oh-parseInt(ho); var hd=oh-ho>h?-1:1; clearInterval(e.si); e.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.height.tw(e,h,ho,hd,s)},20)
        },
        tw:function(e,h,ho,hd,s){
            var oh=e.offsetHeight-ho;
            if(oh==h){clearInterval(e.si)}else{if(oh!=h){e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'}}
        }
    }
}();

TINY.alpha=function(){
    return{
        set:function(e,a,s){
            e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e); var o=e.style.opacity||TINY.style.val(e,'opacity'),
            d=a>o*100?1:-1; e.style.opacity=o; clearInterval(e.ai); e.ai=setInterval(function(){TINY.alpha.tw(e,a,d,s)},20)
        },
        tw:function(e,a,d,s){
            var o=Math.round(e.style.opacity*100);
            if(o==a){clearInterval(e.ai)}else{var n=o+Math.ceil(Math.abs(a-o)/s)*d; e.style.opacity=n/100; e.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+n+')'}
        }
    }
}();

TINY.style=function(){return{val:function(e,p){e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e); return e.currentStyle?e.currentStyle[p]:document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e,null).getPropertyValue(p)}}}();// JavaScript Document


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $('slideshow').style.display='none';
    $('wrapper').style.display='block';
    var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
    window.onload=function(){
        slideshow.auto=false;
        slideshow.speed=5;
        slideshow.link="linkhover";
        slideshow.info="information";
        slideshow.thumbs="slider";
        slideshow.left="slideleft";
        slideshow.right="slideright";
        slideshow.scrollSpeed=4;
        slideshow.spacing=0;
        slideshow.active="#fff";
        slideshow.init("slideshow","image","imgprev","imgnext","imglink");
        
    }
    

    
    
</script>

    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll copy my answer from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125408/clicking-on-a-picture-thumbnail-and-expanding-to-the-center-with-javascript/7125523#7125523):

The term is a lightbox. There any many [jQuery lightbox plugins](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+lightbox). I've had great experience with [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/).

To use them, you could target all anchor tags which have direct children `img` tags, for instance:

```
$('a:has(img)').fancybox();
```

Comment: Yes i've tried with fancybox :) it is great butit won't work when put in this image gallery,you can try it. if you try and succeed pleeease let me know :)

Comment: thanks alex, don't know if i did it right,but i can always uploud it to you via rapidshare or something like this,but here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/HXmWU/2/

Comment: That's far too much JS to debug! Using FancyBox is incredibly simple, I recommend reading the docs and trying again.

Comment: well to be honest, can you use this image gallery from here http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/ and then try to combine it so when you click on the main big image you get the thing that fancybox provides. i've tried that and just couldn't get it....the fancybox somehow works everywhere around, but not in the image gallery

Comment: That's because the large image images aren't wrapper in anchors tags, so FancyBox doesn't have a location for the larger image. You apply FancyBox to *anchor tags*, not to images.

Comment: I have the same script and what I am looking to achieve is if there is only one image, is to display the caption that slides up and stay like that. I know I have to modify the code inside the `TINY.height=function(){}();` but I am not sure which part. Please help...

Comment: @SiKni8, your comment is likely to receive more attention as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).